# How can I map over and object, that contains another Object I want to map over and return JSX from it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

### My Problem

I have mockdata Object that looks like that:

```
topicGroups: {
    0: {
      title: "Languages",
      topics: {
        0: {
          title: "Javascript",
          description: "Everything about Vanilla JS",
          latestTopic:
            "Diskussion] Der ideale asdf Gaming-PC er ideale asdf Gamin(1..."
        },
        1: {
          title: "C#",
          description: "Microsoft's go to language",
          latestTopic: "Main geiles Topic alter"
        }
      }
    },
    1: {
      title: "Coding Partner Search",
      topics: {
        0: {
          title: "Suche nach Liebe",
          description: "Everything about Vanilla JS",
          latestTopic:
            "Diskussion] Der ideale asdf Gaming-PC er ideale asdf Gamin(1..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to achieve the following:

- Map over all the topics groups (to get access to the `title` string and `topics` object.
- Map over the `topics` object inside the first map (so I'm in scope for the group title)
- Return Jsx where I use just the group's title and current topic `title` and `description`

I tried it with several lodash functions, but I can't make it work. The closest I got was to create another fresh object besides `topicGroups`, but then it is difficult to figure out which topics refers to which topicGroups.

**Example how I want to use the jsx and what I want to return:**

```
return groups.map(group =>
      group.topics.map(topic => {
        return (
          <ForumTopicGroup title={group.title}>
            <ForumTopic>{topic.title}</ForumTopic>
          </ForumTopicGroup>
        );
      })
    );
```

What is the best and most clean way to achieve this?

**The reason why I have my data like only with object instead of using arrays is, because I want to work with this data like it comes from firebase (as I will use firebase later on in the application**

Comment: When you say return JSX where you use just the group's title and current topic, can you be a bit more specific about what you want returned?

Comment: @LloydFrancis I'm sorry. Of course, I edited the post with an example.

Comment: If you have an object with keys `0`, `1`, ... , you might want to use an array instead.

Comment: @Tholle Read the last part of the post in bold text. I use it like this because firebase is also fetching the data this way.

Comment: @Tholle as mentioned in the OP, that is a no-go as he wants to work with data that come from firebase

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it points to a broader issue you might want to look into before trying to resolve it like this.

Comment: Yeah I thought of a little helper function, that converts the object to a new object with arrays instead, but then I have the same problem, and don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work like you have written it in your question if you could use arrays, but since objects don't have a `map` method, you could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead to iterate over all the key-value pairs in the objects.

**Example**

```js
const groups = {
  0: {
    title: "Languages",
    topics: {
      0: {
        title: "Javascript",
        description: "Everything about Vanilla JS",
        latestTopic:
          "Diskussion] Der ideale asdf Gaming-PC er ideale asdf Gamin(1..."
      },
      1: {
        title: "C#",
        description: "Microsoft's go to language",
        latestTopic: "Main geiles Topic alter"
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    title: "Coding Partner Search",
    topics: {
      0: {
        title: "Suche nach Liebe",
        description: "Everything about Vanilla JS",
        latestTopic:
          "Diskussion] Der ideale asdf Gaming-PC er ideale asdf Gamin(1..."
      }
    }
  }
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(groups).map(([groupKey, group]) => (
        <div key={groupKey}>
          {Object.entries(group.topics).map(([topicKey, topic]) => {
            return (
              <div key={topicKey}>
                {group.title} - {topic.title}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small JS function for this, hopefully you can use this and convert into JSX.

```
let data = {
  0: {
    title: "Languages",
    topics: {
      0: {
        title: "Javascript",
        description: "Everything about Vanilla JS",
        latestTopic:
          "Diskussion] Der ideale asdf Gaming-PC er ideale asdf Gamin(1..."
      },
      1: {
        title: "C#",
        description: "Microsoft's go to language",
        latestTopic: "Main geiles Topic alter"
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    title: "Coding Partner Search",
    topics: {
      0: {
        title: "Suche nach Liebe",
        description: "Everything about Vanilla JS",
        latestTopic:
          "Diskussion] Der ideale asdf Gaming-PC er ideale asdf Gamin(1..."
      }
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  let { title, topics } = data[key];
  Object.keys(topics).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`Topic title -> ${topics[key].title}`, `Group title -> ${title}`);
  });
});
```